# How to repeat certain part of the regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Input string is :

*John's sandwiches are good bad*

Expression :

```
J.+(\'s|\') sandwich.* are (good|bad)
```

PHP code :

```
preg_match_all("/ Expression /Us", Input string , $matches);
```

Although it will match *'s* and *good* in the input string, I also want to match *bad* by repeating certain part of the expression, which will be `(good|bad)`.

How can I do this kind of job?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow. What do you mean by *by repeating certain part of the expression*?

Comment: Unclear.  Please use a better sample input string to express your expected output.

Comment: @pkpkpk I want to match both good and bad.

Comment: Put the space followed by good|bad in a group and repeat it? `J.+(\'s|\') sandwich.* are( (good|bad))+` Not entirely sure what you're asking for

Comment: @CertainPerformance I already tried that and it match only good twice, not bad.

Comment: Please improve your question.

Comment: I did test it before posting - it *does* match both good and bad

Comment: Are you after `J.+(\'s|\') sandwich.* are (good|\sbad)((?2))` ? See [here](https://regex101.com/r/fUtatz/1).

Comment: @CertainPerformance please do not post solutions as comments.  This can lead to question abandonment and other bad outcomes.

Comment: @CertainPerformance It does not. I tested again.

Comment: @pkpkpk Your solution is correct! Please post that comment as answer.

Comment: @Chyaamoo Please improve your question with php code declares your input string and the execution of your regex.  We need to understand what you _mean_ to capture versus what you mean to match.

Comment: The commented solutions can be optimized.

Comment: After your edit... where is your regex executing code?  What is your coding intention? We don't know if you want the fullstring match, the adjectives as a single string, or separately captured adjectives.  Your question is still unclear and you are less likely to receive the best possible pattern for your task.  Who is upvoting this unclear question?

Comment: Might you have more than two adjectives to capture? Your accepted solution will not accommodate these cases.  Your sample string is not using reasonable English, do you have a more realistic / accurate string that we can see?

Comment: In fact, your accepted solution is strictly requiring 2 adjectives  -- so it will fail if there is only one or greater than two adjectives.

Comment: @mickmackusa That is true. From the OP it appeared that both `good` and `bad` were going to appear. But you make a good point, thank you, I have edited my answer for the recursion of the pattern to be optional.

Comment: The updated accepted solution does not accommodate 3 or more adjectives.  We can edit the answer all day with fringe case possibilities, but this question is unclear and I feel it is not yet ready to be answered -- which is why I voted to close instead of posting a "guess".

Comment: @mickmackusa Yeah that was a sham answer but I had got tired of being pushed around and getting down votes for making a valid question while there was no one offering single answer. Anyway I solved this problem by other method.

Comment: No one was pushing you around.  Your question was not clear and I kept asking for very specofic snd vital details.  When you get downvotes improve your question and they should stop.  It is never too late to improve a question and certainly you can still receive other answers and award the green tick to another answer.  You don't have to give up on this page.

Comment: And for the record, the accepted answer is displaying an incorrect explanation.  `?1` is a "subroutine". The pattern provided is NOT using "recursion".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use regular expression:

`.*?(\bgood\b|\bbad\b)\s?((?1))?`

- `.*?` Match anything lazily.
- `(\bgood\b|\bbad\b)` Capture group. Capture either:

  - Word boundary `\b`, followed by `good`, followed by word boundary `\b`
  - `|` OR.
  - `\b`, followed by `bad`, followed by word boundary `\b`.
- `\s?` Match whitespace optionally.
- `((?1))?` Recurse first pattern and capture in second capturing group optionally.

You may test this regex live [here](https://regex101.com/r/fUtatz/4).

`good` and `bad` are captured in capture groups one and two respectively.

---

Php snippet:

```
<?php
$str = "John's sandwiches are good bad";
$re = "/.*?(\bgood\b|\bbad\b)\s?((?1))?/";
if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[1]);
    print_r($matches[2]);
}
```